# Add new Role to SiteMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlroleprovider

In my program, I have an option for Administrators to add new roles to the database. This, of course, utilizes the `CreateRole` method from `System.Web.Security.Roles`:

```
Roles.CreateRole(newRoleName);
```

Now I'm wondering, is it possible to modify my `SiteMap` during run-time, in such a way that the new role could be added to the list of `roles` in a given `siteMapNode`? For example:

```
<siteMapNode title="Admin Tools" roles="Admin" description="">
```

if I where to insert a new Role called `sampleRole`, the siteMapNode should look like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Admin Tools" roles="Admin,sampleRole" description="">
```

how should my code behind look?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons not to change the file (though it might be possible):

- The file is most likely located in the application directory of your application. If you change a file in this directory (e.g. web.config), IIS will restart the application so that other users might experience interruptions.
- Also the SiteMapProvider might cache the file content for performance reasons, so that your changes are not reflected.
- For security reasons the application pool account should not be able to modify files on the web server.

There is one alternative though: create a custom SiteMapProvider that determines the roles of the nodes so that it matches your requirements. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178431.aspx) for details.